# Opening An Accordion Panel From an External Link

Tags: javascript

Good Day.
I'm aware a similar problem had been addressed in this forum a couple of years ago, but I'm still having difficulty fixing it.
This is the ([link to my test site](http://acrosstheboardgroup.com/section1.html)).

And as you can see, the accordion doesn't even work, talk less of being activated from the external links. What am I doing wrong?
I will GREATLY appreciate your help. THANK YOU.

The javaascripts is

```
var $accordion = $("#accordion"),  
    panelId = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#panel/, "")) || 0;  

$accordion.accordion({  
    active: panelId  
});
$(".opener").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        toOpen = $this.data("panel");
        $accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen);
    return false;
});
```

And the html is

```
<code>     
<a class="opener" data-panel="0" href="section1.html">Open Section 1</a>
<a class="opener" data-panel="1" href="section2.html">Open Section 2</a>
<a class="opener" data-panel="2" href="section3.html">Open Section 3</a>
<a class="opener" data-panel="3" href="section4.html">Open Section 4</a>

<div id="accordion">

<h3>Section 1</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo
            ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>

<h3>Section 2</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
            purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
            velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit
            faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>

<h3>Section 3</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia
            ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3>Section 4</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
            orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel
            est.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</code>
```

Comment: Could you please include your code along with script in your question?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Also, open the browser's console to see the error messages you're getting. Looks like you're calling a function before it exists.

Comment: Thank you Mr Tyler for your response. I've edited my above question for a clearer understanding. Once again, THANK YOU for your help.